# Evaluate the $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x - x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was looking for the integral of $\frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x - x^2}}$

My work:

I was using the reciprocal substitution, where $u = \frac{1}{z}$ and $du = \frac{-1}{z^2}$. Then, I let $x = \frac{1}{z}$ and $dx = \frac{-1}{z^2} dz$, because 
$u = x$ and $du = dx$.

Substituting these expressions to the integral above, we get:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x - x^2}} = \int \frac{ \frac{-1}{z^2}  }{ \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \sqrt{2 \left(\frac{1}{z} \right) - \left ( \frac{1}{z^2} \right)^2}} dz$$
$$ = \int \frac{ \frac{-1}{z^2}  }{ \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2}{z} \right) - \left ( \frac{1}{z^2} \right)^2}} dz$$
$$ = \int \frac{ \frac{-1}{z^2}  }{ \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \sqrt{ \left(\frac{2}{z} \right) - \left ( \frac{1}{z^4} \right)}} dz $$
$$ = \int \frac{ -dz }{ \sqrt{\frac{2z^4 z }{z^5} } } $$
$$ = \int \frac{ -dz }{\frac{\sqrt{2z^4 - z }}{\sqrt{z^4 z}}} $$
$$ = \int \frac{ -dz }{\frac{\sqrt{2z^4 - z }}{z^2 z^{\frac{1}{2}}}} $$
$$ = \int \frac{-z^2 dz }{\frac{\sqrt{2z^4 - z }}{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}} $$
$$ = \int \frac{-z^{\frac{5}{2}} dz }{\sqrt{2z^4 - z }} $$
$$ = \int \frac{-z^{\frac{5}{2}} dz }{\sqrt{z(2z^3 - 1)}} $$
$$ = \int \frac{-z^{\frac{5}{2}} dz }{z^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{(2z^3 - 1)}} $$
$$ = \int \frac{-z^2 dz }{\sqrt{(2z^3 - 1)}} $$

Letting $u = 2z^3 - 1 $ and $du = 6z^2 dz$ or $\frac{-du}{6} = -z^2 dz $ we see that...

$$\int \frac{-z^2 dz }{\sqrt{(2z^3 - 1)}} = \int \frac{\frac{du}{-6}}{\sqrt{u}}$$
$$ = \frac{-1}{6} \int u^{\frac{-1}{2}} du$$
$$ = \frac{-1}{6} (2) u^{\frac{1}{2}} du$$
$$ = \frac{-1}{3} u^{\frac{1}{2}} du$$

Then returning back to the original substitution (from $u$ to $z$):

$$  \frac{-1}{3} u^{\frac{1}{2}} du = \frac{-1}{3} (2z^3 - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} 6z^2 dz$$

Then returning back to the original substitution (from $z$ to $x$):

$$\frac{-1}{3} (2z^3 - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}} 6z^2 dz = -2 (2z^3 - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}z^2 dz$$

Then....
$$ -2 (2z^3 - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}z^2 dz = = -2 \left(2\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^3 - 1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 dx $$
$$ = -2 \left(2\left( \frac{1}{x^3}\right) - 1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{x^4}\right) dx $$
$$ = -2 \left(\left( \frac{2}{x^3}\right) -1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{x^4}\right) dx $$
$$ = -2 \left(\left( \frac{2-x^3}{x^3}\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{1}{x^4}\right) dx $$
$$ = -2 \left(\left( \frac{(2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\right)\left( \frac{1}{x^4}\right) dx $$
$$ =  \left( -2 \frac{(2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\left( \frac{1}{x^4}\right) dx $$
$$ =  \left( -2 \frac{(2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{11}{2}}}\right) dx $$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x - x^2}} =   -2 (2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}{x^{-\frac{11}{2}}} dx $$

I've done my best, but to no avail.....How to evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{2x - x^2}}$ properly using reciprocal substitution?

Comment: Have you tried working backwards from the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+dx%2F(x%5E2+sqrt(2x-x%5E2)))?

Comment: The line $= \frac{-1}{6} (2) u^{\frac{1}{2}} du$ should be $= \frac{-1}{6} (2) u^{\frac{1}{2}}$... then you're basically done

Comment: @KennyLau I  haven't....but if I try it,  it might take me some time......Moreover...I'm studying other topics for our quizzes.......

Comment: $\int \frac{ \frac{-1}{z^2}  }{ \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \sqrt{2 \left(\frac{1}{z} \right) - \left ( \frac{1}{z^2} \right)^2}} dz$ should be $\int \frac{ \frac{-1}{z^2}  }{ \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)^2 \sqrt{2 \left(\frac{1}{z} \right) - \left ( \frac{1}{z} \right)^2}} dz$, then it is reducing to a simple expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you took a very long way; so, let me try.

Fist, complete the square to write 
$$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{2x-x^2}}={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-\left(x-1\right)^2}}$$ Now $x=u+1$ gives $$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{du}{\left(u+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$ Now, use $u=\sin(v)$ which gives $$I={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\cos\left(v\right)}{\left(\sin\left(v\right)+1\right)^2\sqrt{1-\sin^2\left(v\right)}}\,dv={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{dv}{\left(\sin\left(v\right)+1\right)^2}$$ Now, use the tangent half-angle substitution $w=\tan\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)$
$$I={2}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{w^2+1}{\left(w^2+2w+1\right)^2}\,dw=2{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{w^2+1}{\left(w+1\right)^4}\,dw$$ Now $w=z-1$ makes $$I=2\int \frac{z^2-2z+2}{z^4}\,dz$$ which looks to be simple.

Comment: I restrained myself using the reciprocal substitution because I barely had experience using it.......but you're approach? seems nice....I'll try to understand it:-) thanks for the answer.....I couldn't see my error until now though...